# Current date in awk

Tags: text-processing, awk

Is there a constant variable in `awk`, that store today's date? If not, is there a way that can store today's date for daily use?

Let's say we have below file:

```
boo,foo,2016-08-30
foo,boo,2016-07-31
```

And I need to compare the date `$3` in the file, with today's date, regardless what it is.

i.e below script

```bash
awk -F, '{if($3>"2015-08-23"){print $0}}'
```

where `2015-08-23` will be changed by the current date.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There are no built-in functions in standard `awk` to get a date, but
the date can easily be assigned to a variable.

```
awk -F, -v date="$(date +%Y-%m-%d)" '$3>date'
```

or in an `awk` script

```
BEGIN {
    str = "date +%Y-%m-%d";
    str | getline date;
    close(str);
}
$3>date
```

`gawk`, does have built-in [`time functions`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Time-Functions.html#Time-Functions), and `strftime` can be used.

```
gawk -F, 'BEGIN{date=strftime("%Y-%m-%d")}$3>date'
```

Comment: Why quotes (") around $( ) ?

Comment: @Archemar Habit mostly.  It is not necessary if `date`'s format does not have spaces.

Comment: @kdhp, the date format in this way will be for example `15-08-24` while for right comparison it should be `2015-08-24`
is there a way to change it to this format?

Comment: @Azizieh7 The year should be correct, at least according to the [standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/date.html).  It might be that what should be an *upper*-case `Y` is, in fact, in the lower-case.  As for changing the format, you can check your system's `man date`, or the standard linked above.

Comment: You want an `awk` pattern of just `$3>date` (with empty=default action) **no `/.../` slashes**

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Thank you, the errors have been corrected.

Comment: Unfortunately it is a pipe and runs the command only once which can be seen by doing this: `(while true ; do date +'The real time: %H:%M:%S' ; sleep 10 ; done)|awk '{str="date +%H:%M:%S" ; str | getline DateStr; printf("%s: %s\n",DateStr,$0)}'`

Answer (score 6):

using the `getline` workaround:

```
awk -F, ' BEGIN { "date +%Y-%m-%d" | getline a } { if ( $3>a ) { print 0 }} ' file
```

Answer (score 6):

If you like to get the current time_t, this can be done by calling srand() and then call t = srand().

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{srand(); print srand()}'
1440536144
```

This works as posix requires the random function to be initialized with the current time if called without arg and to return the previous seed.

Comment: Note that it works with many `awk` implementations and used to be the most portable way to get the current Unix epoch time at all (let alone in `awk`). But not all. All POSIX requires is that the seed be based on _the time of the day_ (a pretty useless requirement IMO), not specifically the unix epoch time, which allows implementations to use something less predictable and that changes more often than every second. Now I can't remember which awk implementation that doesn't work on.

Comment: Ah! Just found the thread I was vaguely remembering: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.unix.shell/ONhLIUW4CgU So it seems it won't work on OpenBSD.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it by assigning a variable:

```
cat /path/to/file | awk -v date="$(date +'%Y-%m-%d')" -F, '{if($3>date){print $0}}'
```